# Согласование определения, относящегося к двум подлежащим, из которых одно уточняет другое

Tags: согласование, прилагательные, существительные

Как быть, когда одно прилагательное относится к двум и более существительным разного рода, причем одно сущесвительное указывает на другое, то есть имеет место быть уточнение, а не перечисление?

Пример: "Сказанное тобой не делает мою речь, моё утверждение, не верной(ым)." 
Или "Мой сын, моя гордость и вдохновление, недавно удивил всех". Интуитивно я оставил род первого существительного, однако, какое тут действует правило?

P.S Знаю, что это согласование, однако не знаю как оно устроено для уточняющих слов.

Comment: Заголовок надо изменить. Речь идет не и склонениении, а о согласовании, и здесь нужно говорить не о частях речи (прилагательных), а о членах предложения (определениях, сказуемых).

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Формулировка вопроса и сам вопрос недостаточно корректны.** Приведенные примеры не соответствуют названию темы и  не связаны между собой.

1) В первом предложении прилагательное является **дуплексивом**: падеж ему задает глагол-сказуемое, а согласуется оно с существительными-дополнениями.

Обособление надуманное: в такой конструкции уместны **однородные отношения**, например: **Сказанное тобой не делает мою точку зрения, мое понимание вопроса  неверными.** Согласование во множественном числе (препозиция существительных).

2) Во втором предложении выбор числа делается **в обособленной конструкции** и определяется правилами Розенталя:

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Мой сын, **моя гордость и вдохновение**, недавно удивил всех.

Согласование в ед. числе делается для **местоименного** прилагательного **в препозиции** относительно определяемых существительных.

Comment: Спасибо, многое узнал для себя.

Comment: Однако, про первый пример: то, как вы поправили предложение, превратило это в перечисление, то есть "точка зрения" и "понимание вопроса" как отдельные элементы, которые перечисляются. А я имел ввиду случай, когда именно идет уточнение, мол "моя речь, то есть моё утверждение", или же с вашим примером: "точка зрения, то есть моё понимание вопроса". Почему-то мне кажется, что тут не надо множественного числа, когда идет уточнение, а не перечисление. Ведь речь идет об одном элементе в таком случае.

Comment: Stepan, Пример неудачно составлен. Как-то не принято в русском языке говорить о речи, что она верна или неверна.